# Android Studio Drag and Drop not dropping in center of screen

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

When I drag a widget, it drops at the edge of the screen instead of the center where I want it to be. What could be the cause of this?

Comment: post your code.

Comment: Most default layout attributes place objects in order, left-right, top-down.  You will need to learn the various layout designs.

Comment: that is normal for some `ViewGroups`. That **is an expected behavior**

Comment: use RelativeLayout as a Parent layout instead of LinearLayout

Answer (score 1):

the place where your drag and drop gets planted depends on the layout and its attributes that you are using,
example if you are using linear layout with horizontal orientation then widgets will fall one after the other in horizontal fashion

So to achieve your purpose you first need to correctly design and implement your layouts.

Just to give you a short hack, if you make your root layout extend your entire screen ,and then use android:gravity="center" would make all drops fall in the center